# vscode, как сделать подсказку для слова php

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Скачал для `vscode` плагины `PHP IntelliSense`, `PHP Intelephense`, в `.php` файле посреди html тегов пишу `php`, ожидаю, что мне подскажут `<?php ?>`, вот что мне подсказывает редактор:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужна какая-то отдельная настройка, чтобы это работало?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это нельзя сделать без дополнительных настроек. В vs code зайдите: Управление => Настроить пользовательские фрагменты кода => Новый файл с глобальным фрагментом кода => "Вводите имя файла".
Настраиваете:

```
"<?php  ?> short": { // Название
    "scope": "php", // (либо ничего не вводите, если хотите, что б это работало для всех языков)
    "prefix": "php", // (то, что вводите)
    "body": [
    "<?php $1 ?>" // то что будет вводите при enter, 1$ - указывает положение курсора
    ],
    "description": "<?php  ?> short version" // описание
},
```

Вряд ли Вам это поможет через 2 года после заданного ответа, но если кто-то наткнулся на этот ответ, надеюсь, помогло.

Comment: Благодарю, как раз